# Javascript splice removes wrong element

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am somewhat bamboozled over this very simply code not working correcly:

```
 //find the index to be removed
 cardData.likeData.likeUids.forEach ((entry, index) => {
    if (entry === uid){
      uidFound = true
      uidIndex = index
      console.log ("Found uid, index is " + uidIndex)
      //console shows correct index
    }
  })
  let newLikeUids = cardData.likeData.likeUids.splice (uidIndex, 1)
  //instead of deleting the found index, the element before the index is removed... for some reason
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Please provide the necessary input in the script so that we can run and reproduce the issue.

Comment: You really should be using findIndex and not forEach

Comment: Note also that `splice` returns the removed element(s), not the result of the removal -- which happens in-place.

Comment: `const index = cardData.likeData.likeUids.indexOf(uid);
if (index > -1) { cardData.likeData.likeUids.splice(index, 1); }`

Comment: What is `newLikeUids` supposed to be? I think that is the actual problem.

Comment: Hi @VictoriaStuidios What result do you want to store on the `newLikeUids` variable?. removed item OR `cardData.likeData.likeUids` except `cardData.likeData.likeUids[uidIndex]`.

Comment: I think you may need to use `slice` instead of `splice`.

Comment: Please accpet my answer if it helps you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the problem is you probably using the `splice` in the wrong way.

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To access part of an array without modifying it, see slice()

But in your code, you are trying to assign the value of `splice` to a value which will not working.

You probably mix the `slice` and `splice`. I think in this situation, you should use `slice` instead.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what I was doing wrong. I was so used to functions such as string.replace() that I thought I had to reassign the variable. Instead, splice changes the array itself. Many thanks!

Comment: @VictoriaStudios, no problem, I would be appreicated if you could accpet my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `findIndex`. I don't know how your array looks like but in a similar case where you want to remove the first 1 from an array of 1 and 0, you'd write something like this:

```js
const arr = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0];
arr.splice(arr.findIndex(e => e === 1), 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: indexOf is better in this case

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `filter` method of Array can help you

```js
cardData.likeData.likeUids.filter ((entry) => {
    return entry !== uid;
});
```

If you have many uids to remove

you could try

```js
cardData.likeData.likeUids.filter ((entry) => {
    return uids.indexOf(entry) === -1;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: forEach does not do anything with return....

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I forget to change to filter after copying.

Answer (score -1):

I made a small bit of code from what you have written, seems to do what you want:

Changing the UID will decide what is removed from the data.

```
let data = [1,2,3];

let uid = 1;
let foundUidIndex;

data.forEach ((entry, index) => {
    if (entry === uid){
      foundUidIndex = index;
      console.log ("Found uid, index is " + foundUidIndex)
    }
  })
 data.splice(foundUidIndex, 1);
  
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why would you loop back over the array when you are already have the index? `index` is exactly `foundUidIndex`

Comment: Good point! Edited my answer.